# Angular - How to resolve security threats in Angular project

Tags: angular, npm

My Angular-14 project has the following details:

```
Angular CLI: 14.2.2
Node: 16.17.0
Package Manager: npm 8.15.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 14.2.1
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1402.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular   14.2.2
@angular-devkit/core            14.2.2
@angular-devkit/schematics      14.2.2
@angular/cli                    14.2.2
@schematics/angular             14.2.2
rxjs                            7.5.5
typescript                      4.7.3
```

I was about to deploy to production. But when my company security department system scans the project, it displays these issues:

> NPM `debug` prior to 4.3.0 has a Memory Leak when creating `debug` instances inside a function which can have a significant impact in the Availability. This happens since the function `debug` in the file `src/common.js` does not free up used memory.
>
> In NPM `debug`, the `enable` function accepts a regular expression from user input without escaping it. Arbitrary regular expressions could be injected to cause a Denial of Service attack on the user's browser, otherwise known as a ReDoS (Regular Expression Denial of Service). This is a different issue than CVE-2017-16137
>
> The jQuery framework exchanges data using JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) without an associated protection scheme, which allows remote attackers to obtain the data via a web page that retrieves the data through a URL in the SRC attribute of a SCRIPT element and captures the data using other JavaScript code, aka "JavaScript Hijacking." The package maintainer disputes the validity of this vulnerability, hence there is no security fix. However, we considered this a potential issue that affects all the versions

How do I clear these issues?

Answer (score 1):

You question has nothing to do with angular. It has to do with an npm package named "debug" (https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) and jQuery, which is another js library.

Did you put any research effort in understanding the actual issues and trying to find a solution?

Nevertheless here are some suggestions:

1. Upgrade npm "debug" package to a version > 4.3.0 (pretty straightforward)
2. I am not sure how jQuery is used in your project, but usually it is not a good idea to mix multiple frameworks/libraries in order to achieve data binding between HTML and your javascript. Therefore my suggestion is to check where exactly jQuery is used and just replace it with some angular implementation.